# Why runtime.exec() is not executing. when I given sshpass command

Tags: java, runtime.exec, sshpass

Why runtime.exec() is not executing. when I given sshpass command

```
rt.exec("sshpass -p sbsiz scp '/home/surendra/Desktop/remote_backup.txt' root@192.168.59.115:/home/");
```

but when I Run this command directly in terminal it's working like as 
in terminal

```
sshpass -p sbsiz scp '/home/surendra/Desktop/remote_backup.txt' root@192.168.59.115:/home/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the Input Stream and Error Stream from the Process class (return for rt.exec) to see what was the actual error due to which the command was not executed like below:

```
public static void printStream(InputStream is, String type){
try
   {
      InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
      String line=null;
      while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(type + ">" + line);    
   } catch (IOException ioe){
           ioe.printStackTrace();  
   }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    String cmd = "command to execute";
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sshpass -p sbsiz scp '/home/surendra/Desktop/remote_backup.txt' root@192.168.59.115:/home/");
    printStream(proc.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT");
    printStream(proc.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");
}
```

Comment: is it possible changing the file name on remote system ? when it is storing a file

Comment: @SurendrakumarKadiri .. why not to try by providing the filename when you are providing the destination host. If you have issues please post another question for this with linux/scp tags.